# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to use this, but does not work. Not sure of why.

```
androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost(
        navHostController = navHostController,
        route = Graph.ROOT,
        startDestination = Graph.HOME
    ){

    }
```

I get the following error(s):

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

- `NavHost(NavHostController, NavGraph, Modifier = ...) defined in androidx.navigation.compose`
- `NavHost(NavHostController, String, Modifier = ..., String? = ..., NavGraphBuilder.() → Unit) defined in androidx.navigation.compose`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo with `navHostController`. The parameter is `navController`

```
 androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost(
        navController = navHostController,
        //...
  )
```